# Is it alright to have the ViewController holder as a property of the root VC?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, mmdrawercontroller

For all intents and purposes, MMDrawerController basically acts like a UINavigationController, where it holds a ViewController as the root VC.

Is it ok practice to hold the MMDrawerController in a variable in the root VC or should I store a reference to the MMDrawerController in the AppDelegate?

I don't want to run into any memory issues and the reason I ask is because at some point in a Registrations Controller I have to `presentViewController(rootVC)`. This would be a different instance of the root VC and I would either have to store the reference to the MMDrawerController in the Registrations Controller OR maybe call upon the AppDelegate and change the MMDrawerController stored there to the new one for the new Root VC?

I suppose that second option would work fine, but still curious overall about my question in the title.

Also, one last thing: Is there any way when one calls `presentViewController(...)` to make the new ViewController the new initial controller? As it stands, in the new presented controller I would still be able to `dismissViewControllerAnimated(...)` which means that the underlying stack of View Controllers are still in memory. I'd like them dumped from memory. Should I even be concerned about that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, `UIViewController` has a property to return the `UINavigationController`/`UISplitViewController`/`UITabBarController` that it's contained in.

Comment: @dan good to know. I thought about that too.